# ExpatError+ mismatched tag+expatbuilder.py

Tags: django, python-2.7, e-commerce

I am trying to work through Beginning Django e-commerce by Jim McGaw. While working through Chapter-5 , after introducing the google-checkout option I am facing the following error. Can anyone give me some suggestions/possible solutions?

The code snippets is as follows,

```
$ 

    def get_checkout_url(request):
        redirect_url =''
        req = _create_google_checkout_request(request)
        try:
            response_xml = urlopen(req).read()
        except HTTPError, err:
            raise err
        except URLError, err:
            raise err
        else:
            redirect_url = _parse_google_checkout_response(response_xml)
        return redirect_url


    $ def _parse_google_checkout_response(response_xml):
        redirect_url = ""
        print response_xml
        xml_doc = minidom.parseString(response_xml)  # -- Breaks here --
    #   xml_doc = minidom.parse(response_xml)
        root = xml_doc.documentElement
        node = root.childNodes[1]
        if node.tagName == 'redirect-url':
            redirect_url = node.firstChild.data
        if node.tagName == 'error-message':
            raise RuntimeError(node.firstChild.data)
        return redirect_url
```

The Error Log is as follows:

```
**Environment:**

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.1


Traceback:
File "/Users/username/work/pythonwork/djtrunk/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/username/work/pythonwork/ecomstore/cart/views.py" in show_cart
  19.             checkout_url = checkout.get_checkout_url(request)
File "/Users/username/work/pythonwork/ecomstore/checkout/checkout.py" in get_checkout_url
  6.     return google_checkout.get_checkout_url(request)
File "/Users/username/work/pythonwork/ecomstore/checkout/google_checkout.py" in get_checkout_url
  27.         redirect_url = _parse_google_checkout_response(response_xml)
File "/Users/username/work/pythonwork/ecomstore/checkout/google_checkout.py" in _parse_google_checkout_response
  46.     xml_doc = minidom.parseString(response_xml)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py" in parseString
  1924.         return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py" in parseString
  940.     return builder.parseString(string)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py" in parseString
  223.             parser.Parse(string, True)

Exception Type: ExpatError at /cart/
Exception Value: mismatched tag: line 1460, column 4
```

Comment: Hi Hari- I suspect this may be because the response_xml variable returned from the API no longer contains a node named 'redirect-url'. Perhaps it has been renamed, or perhaps it has moved. Any chance you can share the (non-sensitive) contents of response_xml?

Comment: Recently I was in the same exact situation as you, and was receiving the same exact error. After working with the book author Jim McGaw, we were able to resolve this issue. You may want to try retyping the values for your merchant_id, merchant_key, and checkout_url in settings.py. I hope that this helps you. Parker

Comment: @JimMcGaw Will be going through your book second time, starting this weekend will share the details once I hit Google Checkout! Thanks for your help.